# K2 for data integration aka ETL

Tags: k2

My company starts to adopt K2. I am currently fairly ignorant about it. As K2 can be used as a data integration/orchestration layer, I am wondering whether it could also be use for ETL data integration for a data warehouse/data marts. I am looking for potential alternatives to SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K2 uses the Smartobject layer as its data integration layer.

But if you are expecting a full featured ETL data integration, you will be disappointed.

K2 Smartobject provide you with many different channels and mediums for integration. But to do transformation and validation of the data in the Smartobject, it will be a hard sell.

You can definitely build some logic in there.

Bringing it back, K2 Smartobject is build to allow the workflow and forms to pull or push data. Its definitely not design with ETL in mind.

Hope that sum it up for you.

Comment: At the very least with K2 SmartObjects you getting Extract & Transform parts, nothing prevents you to use other SmartObject (e.g. SQL Stored Procedure Based or custom) which will consume data from another one and modify it or form rules to perform Transformation part. It all depends on exact goals and tasks you want to perform IMO.